# How do I find largest valid sequence of parentheses and brackets in a string?

Tags: python, algorithm, stack, dynamic-programming, parentheses

So I have a script I need to write and one of the largest problems boils down to finding the largest valid subsequence within a string. So I have something like

```
"()(({}[](][{[()]}]{})))("
```

as an input and I would need to return

```
"[{[()]}]{}"
```

as an output.

I have tried using a stack like structure like you would do if it was just parentheses but haven't been able to figure out something that works. I'd prefer a solution in python but any guidance anyone can offer will help regardless of language. The efficiency should ideally be better than n^2 since I can think of an O(n^2) solution  using this [How to find validity of a string of parentheses, curly brackets and square brackets?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2509358/how-to-find-validity-of-a-string-of-parentheses-curly-brackets-and-square-brack) and just trying it on different substrings

Comment: Seems to me that the right answer would be everything except that last `(`, or am I misunderstanding something about the question?

Comment: No you are not. I'm just stupid. Edited

Comment: Actually, I liked the input sequence, I just wanted to make sure we agreed on the output sequence :)

Comment: "Valid" here means that an opening parentheses is always followed by its matching closing parentheses, *and* that there are no inside parenthesis pairs open at that moment? Because you don't state what "valid" is.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be solved using dynamic programming. Go through the array recording the longest valid match ending from each index. If you've got the longest match for index i, then it's easy to find the longest match for index i+1: skip backwards the longest match for index i, and then see if the characters surrounding that are matching open/close brackets. Then add the longest match to the left of that too, if any.

Here's some Python code that computes this:

```
def longest_valid(s):
    match = [0] * (len(s) + 1)
    for i in xrange(1, len(s)):
        if s[i] in '({[':
            continue
        open = '({['[')}]'.index(s[i])]
        start = i - 1 - match[i - 1]
        if start < 0: continue
        if s[start] != open: continue
        match[i] = i - start + 1 + match[start - 1]
    best = max(match)
    end = match.index(best)
    return s[end + 1 - best:end + 1]

print longest_valid("()(({}[](][{[()]}]{})))(")
print longest_valid("()(({}[]([{[()]}]{})))(")
print longest_valid("{}[()()()()()()()]")
```

It's O(n) in time and space.

Comment: I think the following "[[(])]" should return "[[]]", but the above code returns ""

Answer (score 1):

This answer uses the following input sequence as an example. The expected output is all of the string except the last `(`.

```
Input:  ()(({}[]([{[()]}]{})))(
Output: ()(({}[]([{[()]}]{})))
```

Step 1 is to find the seeds in the string. A seed is a matched set of symbols: `()`, `[]`, or `{}`. I've given each seed a numerical value to assist the reader in visualizing the seeds.

```
()(({}[]([{[()]}]{})))(
11  2233    44   55
```

Step 2 is to **expand** the seeds into sequences. A sequences is a nested set of symbols: e.g. `[{[()]}]`. So starting from a seed, work outwards, verifying that the enclosing symbols are matched. The search ends at a mismatch, or at the beginning or end of the string. In the example, only seed 4 is enclosing by matching symbols, so only seed 4 is expanded.

```
()(({}[]([{[()]}]{})))(
11  2233 4444444455
```

Step 3 is to **combine** adjacent sequences. Note that there can be two or more adjacent sequences, but in the example there are two adjacent sequences in two places

```
()(({}[]([{[()]}]{})))(
11  2222 4444444444
```

Repeat step 2, treating the combined sequences as seeds. In this example, sequence 4 is enclosed by matching parentheses, so sequence 4 is expanded.

```
()(({}[]([{[()]}]{})))(
11  2222444444444444
```

Repeat step 3, combine sequences

```
()(({}[]([{[()]}]{})))(
11  2222222222222222
```

Repeat step 2, expand

```
()(({}[]([{[()]}]{})))(
1122222222222222222222
```

And combine one more time

```
()(({}[]([{[()]}]{})))(
1111111111111111111111
```

The algorithm ends when there's nothing left to expand, or combine. The longest sequence is the answer.

---

Implementation notes:

I think that you can achieve `O(n)` by expanding/merging one sequence at a time. I would keep the list of sequences in a doubly-linked list (so removal is an `O(1)` operation). Each sequence would be represented by a `start` index, and an `end` index.

Expanding a sequence involves checking the symbols at `array[start-1]` and `array[end+1]`, and then updating the `start`/`end` indexes as appropriate.

Merging involves checking the next and previous sequences in the linked list. If the sequences can be merged, then one sequence is updated to cover the full range, and the other is deleted.

Once an sequence is expanded/merged as much as possible, move to the next sequence in the list. As this new sequence is expanded/merged, it may eventually work its way back to the previous sequence. Hence, after initially creating a doubly-linked list of seeds, one pass through the linked list should be sufficient to expand/merge all of the sequences. Then a second pass through whatever remains of the linked list is needed to find the longest sequence.

Comment: Does this get better than O(n^2) though? It seems like it would be O(n) at each expand/merge step at best since I can't see a great way to do the merging

Comment: @user1984974 I think it'll work in O(n) time. I've added some notes to the end of the answer to explain.

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about arbitrary depth, Franks anser here may apply:
[Regular expression to detect semi-colon terminated C++ for & while loops](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/524548/regular-expression-to-detect-semi-colon-terminated-c-for-while-loops/524624#524624)

If we are talking finite depth, Regex could be your friend (you may want to check performance)

it seems that you're looking for:

- literal square-bracket
- a bunch of chars that aren't end bracket
- close bracket
- open brace
- all chars up to the last close brace
- close brace

so, language-agnostic something like:

```
\[[^]]*\{.*\}
```

this could be used with re.compile with Python, but really it could be any language. Since .* (any char) and [^]] (not-end square brace) are assumed, you can use w+ or d+ for word/digit or other Regex short-hand to refine the solution and speed things up.

Answer (score 0):

This is an old question but I though I'd contribute an O(n) approach that does a single pass through the characters and tracks the matches using a stack.  It rolls up lenghts to the previous embedding group when consecutive balanced groups are found.

```
from collections import deque
def balanced(s):
    groups = {"(":")", "[":"]", "{":"}"}
    result = ""
    starts = deque([["",0,0]])              # stack of [closingChar,position,width]
    for i,c in enumerate(s):
        if c in groups:
            starts.append([groups[c],i,1])  # stack opening groups
        elif c != starts[-1][0]:
            starts = [["",i+1,0]]           # unmatched open/close, clear stack
        else:
            _,p,w   = starts.pop()                     # close group
            if not starts: starts.append(["",p,0])     # maintain ungrouped baseline
            starts[-1][2] = w = starts[-1][2] + w + 1  # roll up group size
            if w-w%2>len(result):                      # track longest
                result = s[starts[-1][1]+w%2:][:w-w%2] # w%2 handles grouped/ungrouped
    return result
```

output:

```
balanced("()(({}[](][{[()]}]{})))(") # [{[()]}]{}

balanced("()(({}[]([{[()]}]{})))(")  # ()(({}[]([{[()]}]{})))

balanced("{}[()()()()()()()]")       # {}[()()()()()()()]

balanced("{[([](){}})]")             # [](){}
```